# Are Shimano Hollowtech II bottom bracket spacers unique?

Tags: maintenance, bottom-bracket, shimano

I'm moving my Shimano Hollowtech II XT crankset and bottom bracket over from a bike with 73mm bottom bracket to a 68mm bike. The only problem is that I only have 1 spacer and now I need 3 bottom bracket spacers.  Do Shimano external bottom brackets have a unique spacer or can I just use any bottom bracket spacers of the correct diameter and thickness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link](http://www.peterverdone.com/wiki/index.php?title=Installing_HollowTech_II_Bottom_Brackets) implies there's no difference, and looking at what the spacers do I agree. Since they're a purely passive component that just fills up space, it's only the physical size that counts. Even with an extra 5mm of spacer I suspect you'll be ok, but I would be somewhat concerned if you had to put all the spacers on one side to maintain chain alignment.

BTW, [this pdf](http://www.enduroforkseals.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderfiles/hollowtech2a.pdf) and [this page](http://www.peterverdone.com/wiki/index.php?title=Hollowtech_II_Bottom_Brackets) match my experience of those BBs. They're not great.

Comment: Thanks moz.  I believe you're answer is correct.  I ended up buying Shimano spacers and they have 2 small notches directly across from one another...I don't know for sure if all other spacers have those notches or even that the notches serves any purpose at all :)